# R Shiny bad dependency from for loop variable. Is there a way to force evaluation?

Tags: r, shiny

A simple way to replicate this issue:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textOutput("helloJohn"),
    br(),
    textOutput("helloJacob"),
    br(),
    textOutput("helloJoe")),  
  server = function(session, input, output) {
    for(name in c("John", "Jacob", "Joe")) {
      output[[paste0("hello", name)]] <- renderText({paste0("hello ", name, "!")})
    }
  })
```

The intention of this code is to have the text "Hello John", "Hello Jacob", "Hello Joe" appear on the page without having to reuse the `renderText` chunk. However, while it seems that the output names get set correctly, when being rendered it seems that `name` gets set to the last value in the for loop, resulting in all the names being "Joe":

[image: All Joe!]

I assume this is due to the way Shiny sets up a dependency graph, however `name` is not a reactive variable, it is available during the initialization. Is there a way I can force evaluation of `name` inside the for loop, similar to Bang Patterns in Haskell?

Comment: Try `force(name)` inside the loop before updating output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap what's in the for loop in `local` and create a local variable `name2` that receives `name`.

```
for(name in c("John", "Jacob", "Joe")) {
  local({
  name2 <- name
  output[[paste0("hello", name2)]] <- renderText({paste0("hello ", name2, "!")})
  })
}
```

Additional info and inspiration for this answer [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/532).

Comment: Reading the provided link, i also found it interesting that using `lapply()` can also solve the problem.