# Repeated values in shiny output variables

Tags: r, shiny, lazy-evaluation

I am having a problem inserting a vector of values into a table in shiny. The problem is it always saves the last entry of the vector into all of the cells that I am trying to manipulate. 
For example:

```
outValues <- c(368,331,334,443,348,324,608,376,354,706)
stations <- c("Station_Electric_Testing_PLx","Station_Wall_Polishing",
              "Station_Dicing_Grooving","Station_Coating",
              "Station_Electric_Testing_PL","Station_PhotoLitho",
              "Station_Face_Polishing","Station_Anealling",
              "Station_CleaningAfter_45","Station_45_Cutting", 
              "Station_Kupelevitz")

         for(stat in stations){
           i <- i+1
           output[[paste0("Out_",stat)]] <- renderText({paste0(outValues[i])})
         }
```

after this code, all values in my table are 706.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Michael

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762513/r-shiny-bad-dependency-from-for-loop-variable-is-there-a-way-to-force-evaluatio and this discussion: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/532

Comment: I will flag it as duplicate, nevermind i think the other question is hard to find and your way of asking still brings value. (see here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292398/3502164)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Shiny bad dependency from for loop variable. Is there a way to force evaluation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762513/r-shiny-bad-dependency-from-for-loop-variable-is-there-a-way-to-force-evaluatio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and the answers is ... complicated. Basically you are falling foul of lazy evaluation, whereby the function is not really evaluated, but a so-called "promise" is stored instead and that is evaluated.

Browsing over the various links you see various solutions, some of which BigDataScientist pointed to (which was a big help), some are relevant, but some are outdated too. The workarounds have changed over time as well - simply declaring it a duplicate does not do the issue justice.

So here is an example that expands a smaller version of your code into a working example with three possible solutions.

- There are 4 possible server functions, `s0`,`s1`,`s2`,`s3`. You switch between them by changing to that parameter in the last line (the `shinyApp(u,s0)` call)
- `s0` is the original code. `s1`,`s2`,`s3` are 3 of the possible workarounds suggested in the links (there are a couple others ones too, but these are the main ones).
- `s1` and `s3` now work. My understanding is that `s2` (force) worked and `s3` did not until R version 3.2.0 - but I don't have a 3.2.0 lying around to check with.
- From version 3.2.0 a change was made which caused `s2` to stop working and `s3` to start working.
- It is not clear to me why they disabled `force`, seems like that was useful functionality.
- This also means that referring to past links is maybe a bit pointless, you have to try things out, and not be surprised when they change in the future.

  ```
  library(shiny)
  outValues <- c(368,331,334,443)
  stations <- c("Station_Electric_Testing_PLx","Station_Wall_Polishing",
                 "Station_Dicing_Grooving","Station_Coating")
  u <- fluidPage(
    verbatimTextOutput("Out_Station_Electric_Testing_PLx"),
    verbatimTextOutput("Out_Station_Wall_Polishing"),
    verbatimTextOutput("Out_Station_Dicing_Grooving"),
    verbatimTextOutput("Out_Station_Coating")
  )
  s0 <- function(input,output,session){
    i <- 0
    for(stat in stations){
      i <- i+1
      output[[paste0("Out_",stat)]] <- renderText({outValues[i]})
    }
  }
  s1 <- function(input,output,session){
    i <- 0
    for(stat in stations){
      i <- i+1
      local({
        txt <- outValues[i]
        output[[paste0("Out_",stat)]] <- renderText({txt})
      })
    }
  }
  s2 <- function(input,output,session){
    i <- 0
    for(stat in stations){
      i <- i+1
      f <- function(i) { force(i); outValues[i] }
      output[[paste0("Out_",stat)]] <- renderText({f(i)})
    }
  }
  s3 <- function(input,output,session){
        lapply(1:4,function(i){
              output[[paste0("Out_",stations[i])]] <- renderText({outValues[i]}) })
  }
  shinyApp(u,s3)
  ```

So `s0` (original) and `s2`(force) yield this output - which is **not** what is desired:

[image]

And `s1` (local), and `s3` (lapply) will get you this output, which is what is wanted:

[image]

Since this is version dependent, here is my session info:
[image]